# search for an item in collection type in VB .NET 1.1

Tags: vb.net, .net-1.1

I am using VB .NET 1.1 and wanted to make sure if inside a key value pair class "Dates" (collection type) a key by name "TerminationDate" exists.

```
If Not Dates.Item("TerminationDate") Is Nothing Then
  'Do x y z'
End if
```

But this is throwing an exception:
Argument Index is not a valid value.

I am very new to VB.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you saw, the [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.collection.contains%28VS.80%29.aspx) method was added in the 2.0 Framework so you can't use it. As far as I can tell, there is no way within the 1.1 Framework to look for the existence of a given key. The only way to do this is to try getting the item at that key and swallowing the exception if its not found. This helper method will do that:

```
Private Shared Function CollectionHasKey(col As Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection, key As String) As Boolean
    Try
        Dim O = col.Item(key)
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

To use it:

```
    Dim MyCol As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection()
    MyCol.Add(New Date(), "D")

    Trace.WriteLine(CollectionHasKey(MyCol, "D"))
    Trace.WriteLine(CollectionHasKey(MyCol, "Q"))
```

Comment: -1: Using try catch blocks as actual logic is a very bad practice and should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: @Bradley Uffner, that is true, but if there's no other way then it is the best way.

Comment: +1: Maybe not best practice, but using .NET 1.1 is also not best practice ;-)

Comment: There are plenty of other ways, looping through the collection for one.

Comment: Have you tried this? Looping through the collection, even in recent framework versions, returns the objects themselves and not the keys. There is no way to enumerate the keys themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Item uses the index value to return the item.  Its position in the collection starting from 0.  If you want to find it using the key:  "TerminationDate"  You would use Contains instead.  Like:

```
If Dates.Contains("TerminationDate") Then
'Do stuff
End If
```

Edited based on comments:

I apologize, I thought because you mentioned key/value you pairs that you had used a specific Collection Type.  a Dictionary.  If you have a Collection of KeyValuePairs you will have to loop thru each item in order to see if the item you want is present.  Like:

```
 Dim Item as keyValuePair = nothing
    For i as integer = 0 to Dates.Count -1
       if Dates.Item(i).Key = "TerminationDate" Then
         Item = Dates.Item(i)
       End if
    Next
If Not Item Is Nothing Then
'Do stuff
End If
```

My 1.1 type names may be off for keyValuePair, and I think Count is directly off Collection, but it may be a method off of Items (if Items is a property).  I don't have the 1.1 framework installed to check.

Contains is a member of dictionary even in 1.1, and would allow you to find an item by key without the loop.  here is more information on that type, if that is something you are interested in:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.dictionarybase(v=VS.71).aspx

Comment: I had tried thar before posting this question but I got this compile error: Contains is not a member of Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection.  Again this is VB.NET 1.1... Thanks...

Comment: Can you show me how you declared the collection, and added items to it?  I am a bit confused about which thing you are actually using because of your use of collection & key value pair.  If its a collection, you will likely need to loop thru the entire thing to find the exact match.  I can give you better suggestions with that information.  Thanks

Comment: The OP is using `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection` which doesn't really behave the same way as normal .Net collections unfortunately.

Comment: Ok, then my type (keyvaluePair) may be wrong, but the overall loop concept should still work.

Comment: You'd think it would but doesn't. Unfortunately looping through the collection only returns the object itself and not any of the key information.

Comment: Yeah, I intended it to loop through the objects so he could examine each one to check whatever is necessary for a match.  I used key in that case because he said key value pair class. I figured he wouldn't get  Argument Index is not a valid value, if it was a collection that accepted a key per item.  That is why I asked if I could see how it was declared and how an item was added.  So that I could be more certain.